# Approximate $2 \alpha + \alpha^2 \Delta T$

Tags: limits

Solving a physics problem, there's a step in the solution that I don't understand.

$2 \alpha + \alpha^2 \Delta T \approx 2 \alpha \Delta T$ when $\Delta T \rightarrow 0$

How is it possible to do this approximation? If $\Delta T \rightarrow 0$ I would rather say that the whole $\Delta T$ term will dissappear so that the result would be $2 \alpha$. Still there's an $\Delta T$ term in the answer.

## EDIT

The task is to define a coefficient for area expansion. Doing this for a square leads me to the correct formula:

$$ \gamma = \frac{2 \alpha \Delta T + \alpha^2 \Delta T^2}{\Delta T} = 2 \alpha + \alpha^2 \Delta T $$

The hint in the solution manual is then:

"Let $\Delta T \rightarrow 0$ to obtain: $\gamma \approx 2 \alpha \Delta T$"

Comment: I am not sure what is going on there, but you might try finishing out the problem two ways. One should be with the weird "extra" $\Delta T$ and the other would be without it. The point being to see what impact it has on the result and trying to conclude the reasoning from there.

Comment: If you don't tell us the original problem, we will never be able to read your mind to know what "$γ$" is supposed to be, nor whether you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is the following. Suppose you have a thin sheet of a metal, in the shape of a square of side $s$, and suppose also that the metal has a coefficient of **linear** expansion $\alpha$.

What that means is that if you increase the temperature of the metal from its current temperature $T_0$ to a temperature $T_1 = T_0 + \Delta T$, then *each* side of the sheet will be expanded to a length that is greater than its length at the starting temperature. The difference in lengths at the two temperatures is proportional to the initial length and to the increase in temperature. The coefficient of proportionality is precisely the coefficient of linear expansion $\alpha$:
$$
\Delta s = \alpha\,s_0\,\Delta T
$$

So, the length of each side, at temperature $T_1$, will be
$$
s_1 = s_0 + \Delta s = s_0\,(1 + \alpha\,\Delta T)
$$

Here's the thing, though. Generally, the coefficient of linear expansion $\alpha$ is also a function of temperature so you can't use a large $\Delta T$ to compute $s_1$.

So, now let's consider what happens to the **area** of the sheet. Since each side expands to $s_1$, the area is expanded to:
$$
A_1 = s_1 \times s_1 = s_0^2\,(1 + \alpha\,\Delta T)^2 = s_0^2\,\left[ 1 + 2\alpha\,\Delta T + \alpha^2(\Delta T)^2 \right]
$$

Since you can't do this for large values of $\Delta T$, you need to consider what happens when $\Delta T$ is small. How do you define small, though? Small relative to what?

The expression inside the square brackets has 3 terms. Let's compare the last two. When is the last term much smaller (in magnitude) than the second one?
$$
\alpha^2(\Delta T)^2 \ll 2\alpha\,|\,\Delta T\,|
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\alpha\,|\,\Delta T\,| \ll 2
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
|\,\Delta T\,| \ll \frac{2}{\alpha}
$$

So, for temperature differences that, in magnitude, are much smaller than $2/\alpha$, the last term in the expression for the area is much smaller than the second and, to a first approximation, you can neglect it and write, instead:
$$
A_1 = s_0^2\,( 1 + 2\alpha\,\Delta T )
$$

Since the area at temperature $T_0$ is $A_0 = s_0^2$, we find that
$$
A_1 = A_0\,( 1 + 2\alpha\,\Delta T )
$$
or, more simply,
$$
\Delta A = 2\alpha\,A_0\,\Delta T
$$

This means the coefficient of **surface** expansion is
$$
\beta = 2\alpha
$$

Note how I didn't have to talk about taking the limit $\Delta T \to 0$. All you need for the result above is the idea that it's fine to neglect a number when it's added to (or subtracted from) a much larger number (in terms of magnitudes). For example, 1.000000 - 0.000001 is approximately equal to 1 because you can neglect the much smaller second term.

Now, the reason to talk about the limit $\Delta T \to 0$ is, again, the fact that we can't use the equations
$$
\Delta s = \alpha\,s_0\,\Delta T
$$
$$
\Delta A = 2\alpha\,A_0\,\Delta T
$$
for large magnitudes of $\Delta T$. Strictly speaking, these two equations (and the volume expansion one too) are valid only in the limit as $\Delta T \to 0$ because $\alpha$ itself depends on the temperature.

I suspect you haven't learned about derivatives and integrals yet, so I'm reluctant to continue from here. If the following doesn't make sense to you, don't worry about it. It will make sense when you learn calculus.

In the limit $\Delta T \to 0$, we can write
$$
\frac{ds}{dT} \equiv \lim_{\Delta T \to 0} \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta T} = s_0\,\alpha(T)
$$
and then
$$
s(T_1) = s(T_0) + \int_{T_0}^{T_1} s_0\,\alpha(T)\,dT
$$
with a similar expression for the area (and volume).

Answer (score 1):

Having had to search "Coefficient of area expansion" (and I did physics at uni) you did not explain that you are working with this
$$
L = L_0\left(1+\alpha\Delta T\right)
$$
so we have
$$
A = L^2 = L_0^2\left(1+2\alpha\Delta T + \alpha^2(\Delta T)^2\right)\approx L_0^2\left(1+2\alpha\Delta T\right) 
$$
you ignore terms higher than $O(\Delta T)$
or 
$$
A = A_0\left(1+2\alpha\Delta T\right) = A_0 + \Delta A
$$
now we have
$$
\frac{A_0+\Delta A}{A_0} = \left(1+2\alpha\Delta T\right)
$$
so the percentage increase of the area is 
$$
\frac{\Delta A}{A_0} = 2\alpha \Delta T
$$